# add confidence interval to splines from quantile regression

Tags: r, plot, spline, quantile

I am using quantreg to fit a quantile regression and have also added some knots based on x-values (quantiles). I now would like to plot this and also have the confidence intervals. Not sure how to do that.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
  #create data    
  x <- seq(0,100,length.out = 100)        
  sig <- 0.1 + 0.05*x 
  b_0 <- 6                                
  b_1 <- 0.1                              
 set.seed(1)                             
 e <- rnorm(100,mean = 0, sd = sig)      
 y <- b_0 + b_1*x + e 

mydata <- data.frame(x,y, age=sample(30:70,100,replace=TRUE), sex=sample(c("Male","Female"),100, replace=TRUE))

#run regression
library(quantreg)
library(splines)
model <- rq(y ~ ns(x, knots=c(25,50,75))+age+sex, tau=0.5, data=mydata ) 

#plot
sp <- c(25,50,75)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x,y=y))+ geom_point()+ geom_quantile(formula=y~ns(x,knots=sp), quantiles=0.5, se=T)
```

This does not show the confidence intervals??
Also, this plot does not take the covariates into account? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can just add to the quantiles argument for a quick result, `geom_quantile(formula = y ~ ns(x, knots = sp), quantiles = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95))`, however, making that a ribbon instead would require a different approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually using results from your `model` in the plot. So I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

You can use `predict` to get quantile regression model-based predictions including confidence intervals, and plot those with `geom_ribbon`:

```
# Get model-based predictions
pred <- as.data.frame(predict(model, data.frame(x = mydata$x, age = mydata$age, sex = mydata$sex), interval = "confidence"));
pred$x <- mydata$x;

#plot
sp <- c(25,50,75);
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(data = pred, aes(x = x, y = fit)) +
    geom_ribbon(data = pred, aes(ymin = lower, ymax = higher, x = x), alpha = 0.4) +
    geom_quantile(formula = y ~ ns(x, knots = sp), quantiles = 0.5, se = T);
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you! Is it possible to make the confidence interval more smooth?

Comment: @user6121484 You'd need to assess the quality of your model fit; In `model` you consider `x`, `age` and `sex` as predictors. Later when (gg)plotting you add the fit from a *different* quantile regression model, where you regress on `x` only. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you remove `age` and `sex` from `model`, you will reproduce the smoother blue fit curve including confidence interval.

Comment: In the model, I am correcting for age and sex. So I want to have to plot the relationship between x and y, corrected for age and sex.

Comment: @user6121484 In that case you probably want to remove the `geom_quantile(...)` bit, because you're only regressing on `x`. Personally, I'd use a GLM rather than quantile regression to explore the role of different predictors on the response `y`. Or if you've only interested in visualising a smooth trend, perhaps a non-parametric LOESS fit. There also exist quantile regression models with smoothing, see e.g. [here](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/2006tutorial/html/quantreg/html/rqss.html).