# How to add confidence intervals to geom_spline (ggformula package)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline, confidence-interval, geom

I have been looking through the documentation but I can not find a way to show confidence intervals,as we can with geom_smooth.

```
ggplot(data_long4,aes(y=Area,x=time,color=condition))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_spline(aes(y=Area,x=time,
                    color=condition), 
                nknots = 5,df=3)
```

Comment: Could you please share some code you tried and data using `dput`?

Answer (score 3):

`ggformula::geom_spline` is a line-only geom. It does not allow confidence intervals. If you want a spline fit to your data with a confidence interval, simply use `geom_smooth` with a b-spline inside an `lm` fit.

We don't have your data, so here is an example using the built-in `iris` data set:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Petal.Length, x = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 3, knots = 5),
                aes(fill = after_scale(color)), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even it is not what you requested a solution could be

```
ggplot(data_long4,aes(y=Area,x=time,color=condition))+
geom_point()+
geom_spline(aes(y=Area,x=time,
                color=condition), 
            nknots = 5,df=3)
+geom_smooth(linetype=0)
```

If you need the actual solution then try [add confidence interval to splines from quantile regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464691/add-confidence-interval-to-splines-from-quantile-regression)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `gf_smooth` from `ggformula`:

> LOESS and linear model smoothers in ggformula.

Here reproducible example:

```r
library(ggformula)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(10, 0, 1),
                 y = runif(10, 0, 1))
gf_smooth(df, y ~ x, se = TRUE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>